# Hardware Back button is not working in (Webview ) windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, webview, back-button

I am having trouble getting the hardware back button to do what I would like it to do for the Windows Phone 8. The app is strictly just webview, so as of now when a back (hardware) button is clicked it closes the app but i want to back just previous page. I put the the URL in constructor like below

```
  namespace Masala
  {
      public partial class Entertainment : PhoneApplicationPage
     {
        public Entertainment()
        {
           InitializeComponent();

           var targetUri = new Uri("http://mobile-masala.com");
           WebBrowser.Navigate(targetUri);
       }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following code in your page.xam.cs to handle back button press...

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if(WebBrowser.CanGoBack)// your code... check the web view that you can go back or it is the main page.
    {
       WebBrowser.GoBack();
        e.Cancel = true; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Your canGoback() method cant recognized ?